# Upgrading Heroku Spring app from Java 7 to Java 11, JDBC is not able to connect to PostgreSQL anymore

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, heroku-postgres, dispatch

I am trying to upgrade my Heroku app from Java 7 to 11. Previously, everything was working fine in the Java 7 version. Since Heroku is now forcing all apps connecting to PostgreSQL to use sslmode=require,  I have to upgrade my pom.xml PostgreSQL JDBC driver version to adapt Heroku latest, PostgreSQL 13 I believe.

So the steps I took Are:

1. Updated my pom.xml with new dependency, I believe these are related dependency need to updated:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
       <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.8</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
       <version>42.1.4</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. and my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` config (followed https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl):

   ```xml
   <beans profile="prod">
       <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
           <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
           <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() + '?sslmode=require' }"/>
           <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
           <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
           <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
               <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
           </property>
           <property name="jpaProperties">
               <props>
                   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                   <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                   <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
               </props>
           </property>
       </bean>
   </beans>
   ```
3. And system.properties

   ```
   java.runtime.version=11
   ```

However, it is giving error:

```
    : at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608195+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608195+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608196+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 26 more
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608473+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3c1bf779': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'clientAuthenticationEntryPoint' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthenticationEntryPoint' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-dispatcher-servlet-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608474+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608474+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608475+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:637)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608475+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608476+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608476+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608476+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608477+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608477+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608478+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 40 more
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608479+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthenticationEntryPoint' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-dispatcher-servlet-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608479+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608479+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:985)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608480+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608480+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608481+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608481+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608481+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608482+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608482+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608483+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 48 more
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608484+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608484+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608489+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608489+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1032)
    2021-03-14T15:19:48.608490+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 56 more
```

Updated error after updating Maven dependency as Flame239 suggested:

The pom.xml looks like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>       
<!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.20.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I get a different error now:

```
    2021-03-14T16:42:12.145844+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145844+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145844+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145844+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145855+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl' defined in file [/app/target/tomcat.4978/work/Tomcat/localhost/_/WEB-INF/classes/com/myproject/service/CustomerServiceImpl.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.SynchronizationType javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()'
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145856+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145856+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145856+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145857+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145857+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145857+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145857+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145858+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145858+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145858+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145859+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 25 more
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145859+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.persistence.SynchronizationType javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()'
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145859+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.<init>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145860+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$buildPersistenceMetadata$0(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:433)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145860+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:668)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145860+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:427)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145861+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:408)
2021-03-14T16:42:12.145861+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:335)
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Your new error would seem to indicate a mismatch between your Hibernate version and javax.persistence/jakarta.persistence dependency you pull in. However, given you received an answer for your original problem, you should have asked a new question with your new problem.

Comment: Actually after some digging, it is issue with java 7 to java 8 upgrading things. please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66628051/heroku-upgrading-spring-app-from-java-7-to-java-8-encountered-java-util-mapentr/66628189#66628189 … in this post, my setup resolves JDBC connection issue with heroku postgres , but still having issue with JSP rendering... if anyone could advise, please jump to this post. thanks

Comment: @sefirosu If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As errors says: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`

In short: in Java 9 JAXB APIs was removed from JDK, so you have to add this dependency manually

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception) will give more details why it happens.

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-Java-9-and-above) you will find how to fix it for spring and they suggest to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```